# Is it a right syntax for async request using fetch api?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am making multiple post request using Fetch API. But when I run this code either one of the request fail. Both the request are working fine separately. Below is the code. Is this a right way to make multiple post request using Fetch API?

```
let req1 = fetch("http://localhost/hplus/statelist", {
method : "post",
headers : {
    "Accept" : "application/json",
    "Content-type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
},
body : ""
}).then(res => res.json());

let req2 = fetch("http://localhost/hplus/citylist", {
method : "post",
headers : {
    "Accept" : "application/json",
    "Content-type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
},
body : "stateid=1"
}).then(res => res.json());

Promise.all([req1, req2]).then(val => console.log(val));
```

Comment: What does "fail" mean? What error do you get?

Comment: What is `localhost/hplus/citylist`, what server is it running? Does it properly handle concurrent requests?

Comment: Fail means can't post data to server and returns undefined index @Bergi

Comment: localhost/hplus/citylist is local server URL. Application is running on XAMPP server

Comment: So it's a problem with your serverside application?

Comment: No, both the request are working fine separately

Comment: The code looks okay to me. Do you have access to your server's code or logs? Check to see whether it's getting both requests, and how it responded to each. Your server may have an issue with two requests in a short time, which you'd want to resolve on the server-side.

Answer (score 0):

```
let req1 = fetch("http://localhost/hplus/statelist", {
method : "post",
headers : {
    "Accept" : "application/json",
    "Content-type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
},
data : ""
})
```

This part already returns a promise.

When you append the `.then()` part, the result of the resolved promise is returned. So, `fetch(something).then(something)` is not a promise.

Promise.all([A list of promises]) would need to have just the promise part.

This is something what you'd need to do.

```
let req1 = fetch("http://localhost/hplus/statelist", {
method : "post",
headers : {
    "Accept" : "application/json",
    "Content-type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
},
data : ""
});

let req2 = fetch("http://localhost/hplus/citylist", {
method : "post",
headers : {
    "Accept" : "application/json",
    "Content-type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
},
body : "stateid=1"
});

Promise.all([req1, req2]).then(val => console.log(val));
```

Comment: But I need a result part not a Promise

Comment: Promise.all([req1, req2]).then(val => console.log(val)); val is the result here, where val[0] has result of req1 and val[1] has result of req2

Comment: I want to point out that this explanation is not correct. `When you append the .then() part, the result of the resolved promise is returned. So, fetch(something).then(something) is not a promise.` This is untrue: when you chain `.then` or `.catch`, etc., to a promise, the result is a new Promise. Anything you return in the handler there is automatically wrapped in a new Promise if it's not already one (however, `res.json()` is already one anyway).